# Chef package resource version attribute not working

Tags: chef-infra

It seems that I have a problem with package resource.
I used like this until some time ago:

```
package "erlang-cosEvent" do
  version "#{version}"
  options "--setopt=obsoletes=0" 
  action :install
end
```

That was a cookbook which has not been updated for about a year now.
Yesterday, when I run the same cookbook on a CentOS7 machine, the version is not recognized.
To have the cookbook working, the workaround I use is this:

```
package "erlang-cosEvent-#{version}" do
  #version "#{version}"
  options "--setopt=obsoletes=0"
  action :install
end
```

Can you please enlighten me? Am I doing something wrong? Did anything changed in this resource?
Thank you.

Comment: did you try to update the chef client\omnibus version?

Comment: I did, but to no avail.